# glossaries package: how change line spacing?

Tags: glossaries, line-spacing

With the `glossaries` package, how does one change the spacing between lines of the printed glossary?

I'm using

```
\makenoidxglossaries
:
:
\printnoidxglossaries
```

so there should be no automatically created groups with extra space between those groups. And in any case, I'm using the `nogroupskip` option:

```
\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}
```

For example, here's a simple source file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,sort=use]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries

% Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{log}{%
   name={\ensuremath{\log x}},
   description={natural log of positive real number $x$},
}
\newglossaryentry{factorial}{%
   name={\ensuremath{n!}},
   description={factorial of nonnegative integer $n$},
}
\newglossaryentry{integral}{%
name={\ensuremath{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}},
description={definite integral of $f$ over interval $[a, b]$},
}

\begin{document}

Factorial $n$ is \gls{factorial}and \gls{log} is the base-$e$ log of $x$.
Evaliuate \gls{integral}.

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output with glossary.]

Because my glossary will consist entirely of symbols (in context), I'm keeping them sorted in the order they appear in the body of the document. So it makes no sense to use something like the `index` style for the glossary, which as I understand things would use `makeindex` to do sorting.

Comment: The distance between two normal lines is given by \baselineskip.  The distance between two paragraphs (groups) is \parskip.  The only question is whether the glossary package resets these values internally.

Comment: Depends on the style. For example, the `list` style has extra spacing as a result of using the `description` environment, whereas the `index` style is more compact. There are [some samples of all predefined glossary styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) that you can view to see which one best suits your requirements. The glossaries package comes with some files with dummy entries (such as `example-glossaries-brief.tex`) to help you construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The link to  "some samples of all predefined glossary styles" helped: with my unsorted glossary of notation, adding `\setglossarystyle{index}` fixed the unwanted interline spacing. (And then I don't need option `nogroupskip` when loading `glossaries`.